# Hibernate Pojo Generator for IBM DB2

Tags: java, database, hibernate, db2, pojo

I used [Hibernate Pojo Generator](http://hibernatepojoge.sourceforge.net/) to generate hibernate stuff. I done it successfully with MySql, but when I tried to generate classes with DB2 it fails. I check hbnpojogen-core-1.4.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar it did not contain DB2 drivers. I added them but it again fails.

I want to know whether **Hibernate Pojo Generator** works with **DB2**?

Comment: What exactly does fail? Any stacktrace, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this tool's website, in the Known Issues section

> Although JDBC is meant to hide database differences, each connector driver has its quirks; therefore at the moment, the generator is only known to work correctly on MySQL databases though it has been reported that MS-SQL support looks pretty good too. Support for other databases, notably PostgreSQL, is coming soon. Other databases are as yet untested (submit reports!)

So it seems that it may not work with DB2.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a quick test using:

```
java -cp db2jcc.jar:db2jcc_license_cu.jar -jar hbnpojogen-core-1.4.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar config.xml
```

... just produced a `ClassNotFoundException`. However, using:

```
java -cp hbnpojogen-core-1.4.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar:db2jcc.jar:db2jcc_license_cu.jar com.felees.hbnpojogen.HbnPojoGen config.xml
```

... produced the following:

```
Reading from config: config.xml
Stage 1: Copying skeletons
Stage 2: Getting commit order in 'PARTIAL' strategy
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
```

With a little more effort, you may be able to get it working.

Comment: Thanks. I did so by adding drivers and also got StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. At one time at got connection failure also.